# In terraform, how do I output an aws_route53_record alias value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.12.x

I'm creating an AWS Route53 record, like this, and it's created with no issues.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name         = "my.domain.com."
  private_zone = true
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name    = "${var.record_name}.${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name}"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = var.alias_record
    zone_id                = var.alias_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Now I want to output the value the alias's name, and I tried

```
output "alias_name" {
  value = aws_route53_record.record.alias.name
}
```

or

```
output "alias_name" {
  value = aws_route53_record.record.alias["name"]
}
```

but get the error

```
Block type "alias" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not
have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a
"for" expression with an "if" clause.
```

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message Terraform returned here is a generic one it returns for all block types that are represented as a set of objects, and so it's giving you some general advice for selecting a set element based on its value or nested values. For example:

```
output "example" {
  # Select the first element from the
  # set whose name is "foo".
  value = [
    for a in aws_route53_record.record.alias : a
    if a.name == "foo"
  ][0]
}
```

That advice is not actually suitable for the specific problem you have here, because you are not "finding elements matching specific criteria", but rather just trying to select the one element you know you wrote, because you've statically defined only a single `alias` block anyway so you know that it will always be there and always be the right one.

To do that, one option is to explicitly convert the set to a list using [the `tolist` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html). The documentation warns that the resulting elements will not be in any particular order, but when there's only one element anyway there can therefore only be one ordering of that element, and so this is safe:

```
output "example" {
  # Select the first element from the
  # set whose name is "foo".
  value = tolist(aws_route53_record.record.alias)[0].name
}
```

---

Providers typically use a set representation for a particular block type if the underlying API considers the objects to be unordered and to have no specific unique identifier. The result is unfortunately then less convenient to use, but using this accurate modelling of the underlying behavior avoids problems where a configuration might work at first but then misbehave later if the remote API starts returning items in a different (arbitrary) order.

The choice of sets for this `alias` block is a little odd since it's defined to only allow zero or one blocks anyway; I suspect this was a historical design quirk that the provider is now preserving for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

The `alias` is set of objects and sets [are](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#set-):

> a collection of unique values that **do not have any** secondary identifiers or ordering.

So you can't index them. Thus in your case to output the alias values you can use:

```
output "alias_name" {
  value = aws_route53_record.record.alias.*.name
}

# or

output "alias_name2" {
  value = aws_route53_record.record.alias[*].name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and it worked. However, can I use a `for` and `if` statements as the error message suggests? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Combining both Marcin's and Martin's answers (thanks to both), here's what I ended up using

```
output "alias_name" {
  value =  tolist(aws_route53_record.record.alias.*.name)[0]
}
```

Marcin's answer gave

```
alias_name = [
  "my-record.domain.com",
]
```

While Martin's answer gave

```
alias_name = {
  "evaluate_target_health" = false
  "name" = "my-record.domain.com"
  "zone_id" = "Z1234ABCDE"
}
```

But combining the two answers like I have above gives

```
alias_name = my-record.domain.com
```

Comment: Sorry... I realize looking back at my answer that I forgot to include the `.name` attribute, and so indeed it was exporting the whole object rather than just the name. I've edited my answer to include `.name` now, but what I did in my answer is functionally equivalent to what you've done in yours, just written out a little differently.